# CIAreaMaximum and CIAreaMinimum return incorrect result or stale result

Tags: macos, core-graphics, core-image

[image: Gray scale image]

When I apply CIAreaMaximum or the CIAreaMinimum filter on attached gray scale image. They return 0.824 and 0.411. However if I read the underlying data myself, the min is 0.34 (86/255) and the max is 0.78 (200/255). The filter code looks like:

```
CIVector *extentRect = [CIVector vectorWithCGRect:image.extent];
CIFilter *maxFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAreaMaximum" ];
[maxFilter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[maxFilter setValue:extentRect forKey:kCIInputExtentKey];
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:[maxFilter outputImage]];
NSColor *color = [bitmap colorAtX:0 y:0];
return color.redComponent; // Since this is gray scale image, any component would do.
```

Here's the code I used to draw CIImage to a bitmap buffer so that I can inspect individual pixel values:

```
// create buffer, colorspace and context
    int pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    int pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (CGImageGetWidth(image) * 4);// 1
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * CGImageGetHeight(image));

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);// 2
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );// 3
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
    }
    bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,// 4
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer, nil];
    bitmapCIContext = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:bitmapContext options:nil];

  // later on use CIContext to draw the ciImage to the bitmap buffer.
  // Here the extent is the entire image
    [bitmapCIContext drawImage:ciImage inRect:ciImage.extent fromRect:ciImage.extent];

    int min = 255;
    int max = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < image.extent.size.height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.extent.size.width; ++x) {
            int index = (y * image.extent.size.width + x) * 4;
            unsigned char value = bitmapData[index];
            if (value < min)
                min = value;
            else if (value > max)
                max = value;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"min = %d (%f), max = %d (%f)", min, (float)min / 255, max, (float)max/255);
```

I wonder if I'm using the filter incorrectly.

There's another issue I have run into with these two filters. When the input of the maximum filter is the output of image accumulater (or composition of accumulator with another CIImage), sometimes the result of maximu filter is obvisouly not the latest data in the accumulater. Some pointer on resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: "When I read the underlying data myself" I don't see you doing that in the above quoted code. What are you talking about, precisely? Show all the code needed to reproduce the issue, please.

Comment: Matt, by that, I meant drawing the image to a RGBA8 bitmap buffer then inspecting the data in buffer. I have added the code snippet of doing that.

Comment: It seems there's bug in my bitmap buffer drawing code. If I switch to use gray scale color space, I do get identical result as using CIFilter. Although I still have issue with CIFIlter using stale data from upstream filters.

Comment: "Although I still have issue with CIFIlter using stale data from upstream filters" But you do understand, do you not, that CIFilter does not actually _do_ anything until you _render_? So in your case, there is _no_ "data" until you have said `[bitmapCIContext drawImage:ciImage inRect:ciImage.extent fromRect:ciImage.extent]` - then and only then do we go back through the chain of filters and _render_ them.

Comment: According to the documentation of [NSBitmapImageRep initWithCIImage:] (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/initWithCIImage:), _"If you specify an object whose rendering was deferred (and thus does not have any pixels available now), this method forces the image to be rendered immediately."_ I will try calling the method you mentioned to explicitly render it though.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are seeing unexpected values because Core Image is color managed be default.  Core Image will covert the input image from its colorspace to CI's working space and calculate the min/max in that space.  Then when you render the 1x1 pixel result image to get the result, CI will color match from the working space to your destination context's output color space.

You can turn all this off by creating the CIContext with the option kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null].

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that will work correctly and efficiently for you...

Here's my output...

> 2015-07-17 14:58:03.751 Chroma Photo Editing Extension[1945:155358]
>   CIAreaMinimum output: 255, 27, 0, 0
>
> 2015-07-17 15:00:08.086 Chroma Photo Editing Extension[2156:157963]
>   CIAreaAverage output: 255, 191, 166, 155
>
> 2015-07-17 15:01:24.047 Chroma Photo Editing Extension[2253:159246]
>   CIAreaMaximum output: 255, 255, 255, 238

...from the following code (for iOS):

```
- (CIImage *)outputImage
{
    [GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage = self.inputImage;
    
    CGRect inputExtent = [[GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage extent];
    CIVector *extent = [CIVector vectorWithX:inputExtent.origin.x
                                           Y:inputExtent.origin.y
                                           Z:inputExtent.size.width
                                           W:inputExtent.size.height];
    CIImage *inputAverage = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAreaMaximum" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, [GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage, kCIInputExtentKey, extent, nil].outputImage;
    size_t rowBytes = 4;
    uint8_t byteBuffer[rowBytes];
    
    [[GlobalContext sharedSingleton].ciContext render:inputAverage toBitmap:byteBuffer rowBytes:rowBytes bounds:[inputAverage extent] format:kCIFormatRGBA8 colorSpace:nil];
    
    int width = inputAverage.extent.size.width;
    int height = inputAverage.extent.size.height;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [[GlobalContext sharedSingleton].ciContext createCGImage:inputAverage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)]);
    
    unsigned int *colorData = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
    unsigned int color = *colorData;
    
    float inputRed = 0.0;
    float inputGreen = 0.0;
    float inputBlue = 0.0;
    short a = color & 0xFF;
    short r = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    short g = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    short b = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
    NSLog(@"CIAreaMaximum output: %d, %d, %d, %d", a, r, g, b);
        
    *colorData = (unsigned int)(r << 8) + ((unsigned int)(g) << 16) + ((unsigned int)(b) << 24) + ((unsigned int)(a));
    //NSLog(@"Second read: %i", colorData);
        
    inputRed = r / 255.0;
    inputGreen = g / 255.0;
    inputBlue = b / 255.0;
    
    CGContextRelease(context);
    
    return [[self dissimilarityKernel] applyWithExtent:[GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage.extent roiCallback:^CGRect(int index, CGRect rect) {
        return CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage.extent), CGRectGetHeight([GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage.extent));
    } arguments:@[[GlobalCIImage sharedSingleton].ciImage, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputRed], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputGreen], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputBlue]]];
}
```